# How to know which table the row is belong tp?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I'm trying to make search query for 3 diffrent tables.
It's working, but now I can't figure out how to know the table which the row is belong to. any ideas?

Here is my query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,city,building,project,dira FROM `clients_to_call` t1 WHERE 
            (t1.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t1.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t1.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t1.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t1.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))
            UNION ALL
            SELECT p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,meeting,status,city,project FROM `clients_closed_1` t2 WHERE 
            (t2.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t2.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t2.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t2.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t2.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))
            UNION ALL
            SELECT p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,client_number1,status,city,project FROM `clients_closed_2` t3 WHERE 
            (t3.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t3.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t3.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t3.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t3.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))");
```

Thank you.

Comment: `select 'whatever_I_want' as woot_a_new_column, ...`. Also, sql injection possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a string indicating the owner table for each part of union. Try this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT 'clients_to_call' owner_table, p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,city,building,project,dira FROM `clients_to_call` t1 WHERE 
            (t1.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t1.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t1.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t1.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t1.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'clients_closed_1' owner_table, p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,meeting,status,city,project FROM `clients_closed_1` t2 WHERE 
            (t2.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t2.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t2.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t2.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t2.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'clients_closed_2' owner_table, p_name,l_name,phone1,phone2,phone3,client_number1,status,city,project FROM `clients_closed_2` t3 WHERE 
            (t3.p_name LIKE '%".$_POST['p_name']."%' && t3.l_name LIKE '%".$_POST['l_name']."%' && (t3.phone1='".$_POST['phone']."' || t3.phone2='".$_POST['phone']."' || t3.phone3='".$_POST['phone']."'))");
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this before.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a constant string to each query like

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `clients_to_call` p_name, l_name, ...
```

Comment: @Strawberry each table contain diffrent col, it's 2 diffrent projects and 1 basic table which contain client's that hasn't been classified yet. thank fot the answer downforme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant string to each query:

```
SELECT *,'clients_to_call' FROM `clients_to_call` WHERE 1
```